# Rich Text Formatting with openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm trying to save rich text to excel using openpyxl.
I'm following [this openpyxl tutorial](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rich_text.html)

I am using python 3.10 and openpyxl 3.1.2

This is my minimal code example:

```
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

rich_string1 = CellRichText(
    'This is a test ',
    TextBlock(InlineFont(b=True), 'xxx'),
    'yyy'
)
ws['A4'] = rich_string1

wb.save('balances.xlsx')
```

However, I get a PermissionError when trying to run it.

Am I missing something or is it a bug?

Comment: as a guess, may be the balances.xlsx file is opened?

Comment: Is it the Openpyxl temp file that is returning the error? Either way it would probably be useful to put the complete error text in the question. Please put in the question, formatted and not in a comment.

Comment: Well in any event, run `pip install lxml` for your environment and try running your code again.